# How to upload music to website like spotify, itunes

Tags: python, spotify, itunes

I would like to write a Python application where it automate the upload process of a music or podcast to iTunes, Spotify, and other streaming platforms. It supposed to get the music in my directory and then upload it into these platforms (ultimately monetize these media).

I have checked the official APIs of the iTunes and Spotify, but it seems that they don't have an upload feature. However, I have seen website, like [this one](https://www.tunecore.com), which claim to upload (to multiple platforms) and monetize the musics.

I would appreciate it if someone could help with this problem. Or tell me how [such website](https://www.tunecore.com) accomplish this task.

Comment: You need to use those 'Online Music Distribution' services (they are officially licensed) to get your music listed there, you cannot do it on your own. This is a different business than uploading a video to YouTube or so.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because - not technical related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this problem could have multiple solutions. One of them would be follow these steps:

1. Get all the data necessary for uploading it in every music distributor :
   -Song name, artists, album, etc ...
2. Store the data in an excel, csv, json or whatever you prefer.
3. Read the data using python, could use pandas library for this
4. Create a Selenium(python library for webscraping) bot that accesses every website and program it to fill all the fields for every website
5. Finally, you could have a bot that reads the data you written and automatically uploads music to all the websites.

NOTE: Only follow these steps if API's from the website are not useful for this task.

PD: It is going to take lot's of time to build this  functionality because you have to program every music distributor website. (7 to 15 days of hardwork) but then you are going to be able to upload tons of music in just a few seconds in all the plataforms.

Last note: Be aware of web scraping policy of every website, maybe they do not permit these type of operations and could ban your IP.